# QR code detected but no available data found in iphone

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Today I am going to use react-native. I went to the official website and followed the steps of Setting up the development environment on the official website. First, I executed
`npm install -g expo-cli`, then executed `expo init AwesomeProject`, and finally executed `expo start`. Then there is a sentence in the console, Scan the QR code above with Expo Go (Android) or the Camera app (iOS). But when I use the iphone xr camera to scan, this message appeared, QR code detected but no available data found.

My computer operating system is Windows.

How can I develop a ios app with my iphone and Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need "Expo Go" app installed on your iPhone before you scan the QR.
Install it from appstore and after successful installation try to scan the QR again.

Comment: Thank you! I successfully saw my app project on my phone.